# What software was used to create the diagrams in the Git Community Book?

Tags: diagrams

The diagrams in the [Git Community Book](http://book.git-scm.com/4_rebasing.html) are excellent and I'd like to know what software was used to create them.  I emailed the author, but he didn't respond, so does anyone else know?

(This question was raised by request within [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663733/signing-tags-in-git/5664386#5664386)).

[image]

Comment: My guess would be [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org), and/or [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/features/).

Comment: I'd have said OmniGraffle too. At least judging from the arrows and rounded corners.

Comment: Cheers guys - I guess we'll never know for sure unless the Author makes a visit to this site (which is possible).

Comment: The file extension **.graffle** [here](https://github.com/progit/progit/tree/master/figures-source) is suspicious... 
It seems Omnigraffle.

Answer (score 1):

[yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) is a powerful and free graph editor that produces really nice graphs.

I use it often for my needs. It provides automatic layout and many shape / line options.

These graphs could have been produced by this program.

Comment: They did not ask a generic software-recommendation question (which would be closed anyway since it has been asked numerous times already); they were asking about the *specific* program that was used to make the Git diagrams, and comparing the [graphs](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_gallery.html), it does not look like yEd was used.